# azure AD policy custom config not working

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have basic Active directory created in azure portal and we have web applications registered there. Currently we are using default config of AD.
But we have situation like for the application we need to set inactive timeout for 30 mins.
I was using this methods:

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId xxxxxx
```

Create new ad policy:

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"MaxInactiveTime":"00:30:00"}}') -DisplayName "WebApiDefaultPolicyScenario" -IsOrganizationDefault $false -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

Adding policy to app.

```
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id 3536sdt63fc-49d8-97de-3acb81aebfce -RefObjectId 43strt-4f1c-4d06-a554-5edbafe799bf
```

But when I try to test inactive time out I am not seeing the change.

Comment: `MaxInactiveTime` is for `Refresh Token Max Inactive Time`. The inactive time is also determined by others too. like acess_token. It's also determined by the authentication flow/method the app is using.  I think this policy should have taken effective already.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug, I have seen a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54096050/claims-not-showing-after-applying-new-azure-ad-policy/54105238#54105238). The command works fine, we can see the policy which we added to the service principal via [`Get-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadserviceprincipalpolicy?view=azureadps-2.0-preview), but it seems not to affect. If it is necessary, you could [open an issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues) in the Github.

[image]